# R knowing part sample value, mean and standard deviation find other values

Tags: r, solver

R code:
Knowing 5 data 2, 1, 3, 5, 6 Find the other 5 data so that the mean is 4.5 and the standard deviation is 1.4, and the minimum value of these numbers is greater than 1, and the maximum value is less than 10.
This is what chatgpt gives:

```
library(lpSolve)

# input data
d <- c(2, 1, 3, 5, 6)
n <- length(d)
target_mean <- 4.5
target_sd <- 1.4

# define solver model
lp_model <- lp(direction = "min",
               objective.in = c(rep(0, n), rep(1, n)),  # aim function
               const.mat = rbind(c(rep(1, n), rep(0, n)),  # Constraint Matrix 1: Means
                                 c(d, rep(0, n)),  # Constraint Matrix 2: Sample Variance
                                 c(diag(n), rep(0, n)),  # Constraint Matrix 3: Data Range
                                 c(-diag(n), rep(0, n))), 
               const.dir = c("=", "=", ">=", ">="),  # constraint symbol
               const.rhs = c(target_mean, target_sd, rep(c(1,-1), each=n/2) %*% c(d,rep(1,n)) + 1, 
                             rep(c(-1,1), each=n/2) %*% c(d,rep(1,n)) + 9))

# print
if (lp_model$status == 0) {
  new_data <- lp_model$solution[1:n]
  print(new_data)
} else {
  cat("No solution found.")
}
```

however error occurs:

> Error in rep(c(1, -1), each = n/2) %*% c(d, rep(1, n)) :
> non-conformable arguments

this was what chatgpt answers:

> This error occurs when the dimensions of the two matrices being
> multiplied are not compatible. In this case, it is likely that the
> length of the vector "d" or the number of elements in the vector
> created by "rep(1, n)" does not match the length of the vector created
> by "rep(c(1, -1), each = n/2)".
>
> To fix the error, you need to ensure that both matrices have
> compatible dimensions by adjusting the length or number of elements in
> the vectors being used or by changing the way they are being
> multiplied.

**However, I do not know how to work out, need your timely help, thank you!**
If you have any faster solution, hope to tell me!

Comment: It's not possible. Try `x <- rep(((length(d) + n)*target_mean - sum(d))/n, n); mean(x); sd(x)`. Setting all of the missing values to be the same will minimize the variance for a fixed mean. You won't get a standard deviation less than 1.804316 if the mean is 4.5.